# Do hospitals in the Schengen area accept Schengen health insurance printout as proof of insurance?

Tags: schengen, travel-insurance-claim

I already have a Schengen visa, for which I had shown a particular Schengen insurance policy I bought from a German company (not specifying the name in case the moderators mistake this question for spam).

I am planning to carry this policy's (which cost me 13 euros) printout (they do not issue special cards) when I travel. If unfortunately I had to visit a doctor/hospital during this short trip, do hospitals in Schengen area accept policies like this? Or will I have to pay out of pocket?

Comment: I believe the best people to ask are the insurance company. Many companies have many different types of agreement and any answer from here will be speculation. In any case the Schengen area is comprised of multiple countries who do things differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend entirely on the conditions of your insurance policy. Settlements can be handled both ways.

Most travel health insurances sold *in* Germany for use abroad do not pay directly to a foreign health care provider, but require the insurance holder to settle the payment on site and get a bill for the services, which will be reimbursed later. This can of course be quite inconvenient, as such bills can easily get much higher than what many tourists are able to pay unexpectedly.

Only some health insurances allow a direct settlement between the health care provider and the insurance, their foreign office or local representatives.

The same will be the case for travel health care insurances sold to foreigners for *use* in Germany.

Comment: Are there any well-known insurances that allow such a direct settlement?

Comment: @CHJ That would be a shopping question, which is not on topic here.